# Django admin page loses styling when travelled to from link

Tags: django, django-admin, django-urls

When I travel directly to the admin page of my django website by entering http://localhost:8000/admin/ in my address bar, the admin page is styled as it should be.
However, I need to create a link in my navigation bar that takes the user to the admin page but when the admin page is accessed from this nav link the normal admin styling disappears even though it appears to take me to the exact same web address.

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrdOF.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FPrS.png)

When I inspect the site it instead seems to be recieving styling from my jquery mobile stylesheet instead.
Any idea why this may be the case only when travelling to the admin address from the link?

EDIT:
Here is the html code for the nav. The result is the same regardless of using href='/admin/' or href="{% url 'admin:index' %}"

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{% trans 'Staff Login' %}</a>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Here are my urls.py files for each of my apps:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='form_page'),
    path('search/', views.search_page, name='search_page'),
    path('list/', views.list_skills, name='list_skills_page'),
    path('skill/<slug:code>/', views.show_skill, name='show_skill_page'),
    path('select/<slug:code_1>/', views.select_second, name='select_second'),
    path('select/<slug:code_1>/<slug:code_2>/', views.view_second, name='view_second'),
    path('language_preferences/', views.language_preferences_page, name='language_preferences_page')
]
```

- 

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('Generator.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
]
```

Also, I have noticed that when inspecting the source in my browser the admin static files do not appear in the page sources when viewing the admin site after clicking the anchor link (left) but are present if I directly enter the admin address in my search bar (right).
[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7lAt.png)

Comment: can you show me urls.py and nav html code ?

Comment: I have edited my post to include this

Comment: can you do this ,,, python manage.py collectstatic ,,, python manage.py makemigrations ,,, python manage.py migrate ,, then runserver and use other browser it should work

Comment: also before do this i mean python manage etc .. you must add static file your project then add path in settings.py

Comment: @KokHyvv Thank you but I have tried these steps already and it has not seemed to help

Comment: Theoretically, it shouldn't change anything if you visit the page via the link or directly.
Are the stylesheets linked in the head of the HTML code when you access the page via link? If yes, are requests sent to the server (see logs)? Does (force) reloading the page help? (in Firefox (CTRL+)F5, might be the same in Chrome) If it does, then this is most probably a browser or caching issue. If not, then I have absolutely no clue what's going on there.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Rafael, I tried these steps and have now managed to reolve the issue another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED:

I found that some jquery js found in my base html template seemed to be interfering with the admin static files and stopping them from being served when I navigated to the admin site from the link in the navigation bar (no idea why!)

removing the following line fixed the admin style issue when navigating from the link:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

so I simply wrote a javascript script to remove this jquery resource from the DOM when the link is clicked and the issue was resolved.